# Creating a rtsp client for live audio and video broadcasting in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtsp-client

I am trying to create a RTSP client which live broadcast Audio and Video. I modified the iOS code at link http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm and able to broadcast the Video to server properly. But now i am facing issues in broadcasting the audio part. In the link example the code is written in such a way that it writes the Video data to file and than reads the data from the file and upload the NALU's video packets to RTSP server.

For Audio part i am not sure how to proceed on it. Right now what i have tried is that get the audio buffer from mic and than broadcast it to the server directly by adding RTP headers and ALU.. but This approach is not properly working as Audio starts lagging behind and lag increases with time. Can someone let me know if there is some better approach to achieve this and with lip sycn audio/video.

Comment: :- Can you please guide me on how to broadcast audio ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you losing any packets on the client?  If so, you need to leave "space."   If you receive packet 1,2,3,4,6,7, You need to leave space for the missing packet (5).

The other possibility is a what is known as a clock drift problem.  The clock (crystal) on your client and server are not perfectly in sync with each other.
This can be caused by environment, temperature changes, etc.

Let's say in a perfect world your server is producing audio samples 20ms audio samples at 48000 hz.  Your client is playing them back using a sample rate of 48000 hz.   Realistically your client and server are not exactly 48000hz.  Your server might be 48000.001 and your client might be 47999.9998.   So your server might be delivering faster than your client or vise versa.   You would either consume packets too fast and under run the buffer or lag too far behind and overflow the client buffer.   In your case, it sounds like the client is playing back too slow and slowly lagging behind the server.   You might only lag a couple milliseconds per minute but the issue will keep continuing and it will look like a 1970s lip synced Kung Fu movie.

In other devices, there is often a common clock line to keep things in sync.  For example, Video camera clocks, midi clocks. multitrack recorder clocks.

When you deliver data over IP, there is no common clock shared between a client and server.  So your issue concerns syncing clocks between disparate devices with no.   I have successfully solved this problem using this general approach:

- A) Let the client count the rate of packets that come in over a period of time.
- B) Let the client count the rate that the packets are consumed (played back).
- C) Adjust the sample rate of the client based on A and B.

So your client requires that you adjust the sample rate of the playback.  So yes you play it faster or slower.   Note that the playback rate change will be very very subtle.  You might set the sample rate to be 48000.0001 hz instead of 48000 hz.   The difference in pitch would be undetectable by humans as it would only cause a fraction a cent difference in pitch.  I gave an explanation of a very simplified approach.  There many other nuances and edge cases that must be considered when developing such a control system.  You don't just set it and forget it.  You need a control system to manage the playback.

An interesting test to demonstrate this is to take two devices with the exact same file.  A long recording (say 3 hours) is best.   Start them at the same time.   After 3 hours of playback, you will notice that one is ahead of the other.

This post explains that [it is NOT a trivial task to stream audio and video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948346/voip-rtp-streaming-from-to-server-in-java-to-from-android/31006401#31006401).

Comment: Hi Jaybers,  I am not sure that but it seems like i am sending packets too fast. Can you please let me know how can i add a delay in sending the packets from my side and how to calculate what delay needs to be added. any formula or calculations for that?

Comment: You want to send packets at the same rate they are consumed.  So you want to stream a 100 meg file, you can't just loop through it without some sort of delay between packets to do a realtime stream.  If you want to buffer the stream, send a chunk of data then let the client tell the server it wants more. 
Do not put sleep() calls in.  This is a hack and it is not accurate.
If you want to send data at the same rate as it consumes, have an audioPlayer on your server process the file and provide callbacks say every 20ms (or whatever chunk size you decide to use.