# How to send/sync audio stream over a network

Tags: c, audio-streaming

I am currently working on a streaming application to stream my local (24/96, 16/48) wav files on my home network.

I use a loop to send a chunk of audio continuously and simulate playback, but I have problem getting the playback to sync correctly between the sender and receiver.

This is the loop:

```
    -- using a block size of 192 frames
    int bufsz = 192 * bytes_per_frame;
    char buf [ bufsz ];
    int bytesread = buffer_callback (buf, bufsz);
    int bytes_per_second = bytes_per_frame * samplerate; 
    sleeptime = bytesread * 1000 / bytes_per_second * 1000;
    -- doing this to avoid gaps
    sleeptime = sleeptime - 200;
    usleep (sleeptime);
```

The problem: 
There is a delay which accumulates over time. The audio keeps playing on the receiver side for some time when stopped on the server side. How do I sync the playback correctly? Am I using the right buffer size? Is sleeptime calculated correctly? I guess it's the subtraction of 200 from sleeptime that accumulates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what delay? why do you sleep?

Comment: Is the audio choppy then?

Comment: I sleep to simulate playback. The delay is when I hit stop on server frontend, the playback does not stop immediately at the client. Hope I am clear.

Comment: No, the audio is not choppy, only if I don't subtract 200 from sleeptime, then it's choppy.

Comment: I also sleep to make the progress indicators on the frontend to sync with the playback. If I don't, I loose control of what client is playing, and when I seek ahead the client may not respond in time.

Comment: You need a better protocol, eg. one where a priority command like 'stop playing' flushes the queue of send buffers and sends immediate 'stop playing' message to the peer which, when it gets it, flushes the received queue of cached buffers and stops the playback.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Since I'm not implementing from scratch, it is difficult to use such protocol, but ffmpeg did the trick. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a very interesting problem: Your sender and your receiver are likely running on a different clocks. It sounds like that your receiver clock is slightly slower - so your receiver doesn't play the samples fast enough.
You have a bunch of different options:

- Use a MPEG-2 Transport Stream and recover the sender clock using
  PCR.
- Have an input queue in your receiver and then up or down sample your
  incoming audio depending if your queue over or under flows.
- Synchronize the sender and receiver clocks perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially solved this by replacing sox with ffmpeg and using -re flag to prevent the client from receiving too much. Now, it syncs much better.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248008/creating-a-rtsp-client-for-live-audio-and-video-brodcasting-in-objective-c/32323550#32323550) the issue of your issue of clock drift.  Because your audio source and audio place back devices do not have a shared common clock, you will have clock drift.  This is when the clock crystal vary by some amount.  If the source is providing data too slowly, your receiver will run on of data and starve.  If your source provides data too quickly, it might overflow some buffers on the receiver.  The answer in the link explains the problem and some work arounds.