# AurioTouch purpose of AudioBufferList

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audio-streaming

In the Apple provided aurioTouch project, I heard that the AudioBufferList ioData in the AudioController file under the performRender() function carries the audio data from the mic to the audio player? Can anyone confirm this? Here is the code:

```
// Render callback function
static OSStatus performRender (void                         *inRefCon,
                           AudioUnitRenderActionFlags   *ioActionFlags,
                           const AudioTimeStamp         *inTimeStamp,
                           UInt32                       inBusNumber,
                           UInt32                       inNumberFrames,
                           AudioBufferList              *ioData)
{
OSStatus err = noErr;
if (*cd.audioChainIsBeingReconstructed == NO)
{
    // we are calling AudioUnitRender on the input bus of AURemoteIO
    // this will store the audio data captured by the microphone in ioData
    err = AudioUnitRender(cd.rioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData);

    // filter out the DC component of the signal
    cd.dcRejectionFilter->ProcessInplace((Float32*) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames);

    // based on the current display mode, copy the required data to the buffer manager
    if (cd.bufferManager->GetDisplayMode() == aurioTouchDisplayModeOscilloscopeWaveform)
    {
        cd.bufferManager->CopyAudioDataToDrawBuffer((Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames);
    }

    else if ((cd.bufferManager->GetDisplayMode() == aurioTouchDisplayModeSpectrum) || (cd.bufferManager->GetDisplayMode() == aurioTouchDisplayModeOscilloscopeFFT))
    {
        if (cd.bufferManager->NeedsNewFFTData())
            cd.bufferManager->CopyAudioDataToFFTInputBuffer((Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames);
    }

    // mute audio if needed
    if (*cd.muteAudio)
    {
        for (UInt32 i=0; i<ioData->mNumberBuffers; ++i)
            memset(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, 0, ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
    }
}

return err;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RemoteIO audio unit is a component that is able to access both audio hardware input (microphones) and output (speaker).

The input gets data from the mic or a buffer.  The output puts audio data to the speaker or a buffer.

Since the input gets data from the microphone, you can do whatever you want with it.  You could save it to a file.  You could send it up a network stream.  You could keep it in memory.

For the output, the audio output device and speaker are requesting data to be played.

So in the software your provided, all they did is connect the microphone to the speaker as a direct audio pass through.

The function  `performRender()` is called periodically by the audio system and it says "Gimme some audio samples to play."   Inside that function, it reads from data produced by the mic in the line:  `AudioUnitRender(cd.rioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData);`

You could replace the insides of `performRender()` and make your own audio data programmatically, read from a file or buffer , etc.  All they did is just read from the mic data.

As for your question about the purpose of AudioBufferList.  That just provides a list of buffers where each buffer is a channel.  Sometimes you have more than one channel of audio depending on the format (mono, stereo, stereo interleaved, mixer channels, etc), and type of unit.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, that really cleared things up. This is an incredibly broad question, but I'm really struggling with sending the mic data to another phone using this framework called Multipeer Connectivity and I've been feeling out of depth with audio stuff, so I have to ask it. I tried initializing an NSStream and sending the "iodata" through to another phone. Though it recieved the data, it didn't do anything, which makes sense now, because I wasn't sending it the full mic data. My question is how would you send a stream of mic data to a different phone in real time?

Comment: Yes very broad question.  I don't know much about the framework you mention.  However, when you are streaming, you need address these questions and limitations:
1) Bandwidth constraints?  (eg LAN vs WAN )
2) Is your network communication protocol reliable or unreliable ( rg tcp vs udp)?  How will you handle data losses if unreliable?
3) Define your realtime latency constraint.  (30ms, 100ms, 2 seconds?)  No system as 0 latency.
4) How are you going to compress data?  (Opus is very good for low latency streaming)
5) Are you sending data to one person or many people?

Comment: But it's not like I can send the parameters in the function AudioUnitRender(cd.rioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, ioData); to a different phone, right? Somehow it needs to be made into a compressed version of that data, then sent along.

Comment: The info you care about is in ioData.   That's where the raw stream is.  Compress it if you would like and send it on up a network.  

 Audio streaming is not a trivial task.  There so many extra things that you need to think about:  Buffering, overruns, underruns, edge cases, network bandwidth,  compression, losses, loss concealment,  network jitter.
See this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948346/voip-rtp-streaming-from-to-server-in-java-to-from-android/31006401#31006401

Comment: @jaybers Could you help me to fill mic buffer with my own audio data? What should I do? I am basically trying to fill audio buffers for a virtual input device